# Complete game Ojanen - Ridala , Helsinki 1959

Tags: blunder, rook-endgame

Entry 117 in [Tim Krabbe’s Diary](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary_6.htm) shows a case of fatal automatism.

```
[Title "Ojanen - Ridala, Helsinki 1959 "]
[FEN "R7/P4k2/8/8/7K/8/r7/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rh8 Rh2+
```

In the game Ojanen-Ridala, Helsinki 1959, White saw a routine win, which was a loss in the concrete case.

Does anyone know of the complete game?

Comment: To save others the trouble, it's not in ChessBase's Mega Database.

Comment: It's not either in the millionbase. But you find Ridala-Ojanen, Helsinki 1959 there. So close!

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to find the complete game, **therefore must conclude that it is no longer available**. These are the methods I used:

- Searching the *Chessmaster* and *Fritz for Fun* databases yields no results. Referencing the comments  by @dfan and @Iodebari, the complete game is not in Chessbase's *Mega Database* or in *MillionBase*
- Google doesn't return it
- I've emailed Tim Krabbe, the author of the site linked to in the question, but have received no response
- The game is not in any books that I have in my (admittedly limited) chess library. E.g. the game does not feature in *Mastering Chess Strategy* by Johan Hellsten

---

**PS. A note about topicality:**

On meta I've asked a question about how to answer questions where I don't believe there is an answer. If you feel that this should have been a comment instead of an answer, please feed back on the meta question [What do we do with questions that I don't think there is an answer to?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/438/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-i-dont-think-there-is-an-answer-to)

Additionally, if you have an answer to the question, I would love to see it. My own research methods are limited and I don't mind being proven wrong if someone can find the complete game.